# Create an Email Template thats looks good in any mail services in html

Tags: html, email-templates

Is there anyway how to create an email template that will not broken in gmail and outlook mail services.

Any idea please, I highly appreciate if you can help me with this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. In simple words yes there is but you will need to read and practice a little. Here is a link of how to do it. https://litmus.com/blog/understanding-responsive-and-hybrid-email-design.

Comment: is it fully responsive? anyway what is SO?

Comment: There is a difference between hybrid and responsive. If you read the article it will tell you how and where the differences are. Hybrid will make stacking easy for you. It is not dependent on media queries to do the stacking.

Comment: I just created an Email Template when i tried to send it to gmail it works fine unless the fonts are changed, but then in outlook it ruins everything from my design.

Comment: can you give me your email , i will send it to you

Comment: I would suggest changing this question and making it so you ask help for your email rather than a general opinion based question.

Comment: I just send the email template to your email.

Comment: i will post a new question later then. thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Creating a robust email HTML is a very tough job. The main problem is that there are no email HTML standards and probably you have to support various email clients. To be honest, outlook is one of the most problematic ones.

We have been in the field of email coding for a long time, and we wrote an [article series](http://blog.edmdesigner.com/tag/modern-html-email-tutorial/) about this topic. If you want to know the fundamentals, I recommend you to read it.

If you don't have that much time, or you don't want to code, you can try out our [email editor](https://app.edmdesigner.com/login) as well.

I hope it helps.